# Word or phrase for bad memories?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

How do I describe a bad memory or flashback?

For example, when I've had a bad experience, and I'm in the same situation again (sort of like a negative *déjà vu*), I could say:

> Forcing myself to concentrate, I tried to ignore the ****insert phrase here****.

Comment: At some degree of severity what you describe becomes PTSD.

Comment: True, but I don't mean it _that_ drastically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metaphorical expression used quite often hereabouts is **ghost of the past**.

The Urban Dictionary definition is fine here:

> *ghost of the past*
>
> Horrific event [the memory of which one wishes] to be rid of, or person that did a horrible act towards you
>
> *I wanted to get rid of the ghost of the past, my little goat dying* ...

The related **lay the ghost of something (to rest)** is relevant:

> *lay the ghost of something (to rest)*
>
> ​ to finally stop being worried or upset about something that has
>   worried or upset you for a long time:
>
> *With one stunning performance, he has laid to rest the ghost of all his defeats last season.*

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lay-the-ghost-of-sth-to-rest)]